Excel VBA. Определение статуса порта

При выполнении этого кода возвращается статус порта (Open либо Close).

Sub TestPortCheck()
    Dim ip As String
    Dim port As String
    Dim result As String
    
    ip = "127.0.0.1"
    port = "1234"
    
    result = CheckPortWithPowerShell(ip, port)
    
    ' Выведите результат в окно отладки
    Debug.Print "Result for IP " & ip & " and Port " & port & ": " & result
End Sub


При выполнении этого кода возвращается статус порта (всегда Open).

Sub TestPortCheck2()
    Dim ip As String
    Dim port As String
    Dim result As String
    
    ' Получение IP и порта из ячеек
    ip = Range("A2").Value
    port = Range("B2").Value
    
    ' Проверка порта с помощью PowerShell
    result = CheckPortWithPowerShell(ip, port)
    
    ' Выведите результат в окно отладки
    Debug.Print "Result for IP " & ip & " and Port " & port & ": " & result
End Sub

В чем ошибка?
По какой причине во втором варианте может неправильно определится статус порта?
Что нужно поменять в коде?

Проверьте данные в ячейках A2:B2 активного листа.

Данные в ячейках имеются.
Вот информация которую выдает Debug.Print:
IP: 93.88.93.29
, Port: 456, Output: 'Open'
Filtered Output: 'Open'
Result for IP 93.88.93.29
and Port 456: Open
тут 93.88.93.29 содержимое поля А2, а 456 это содержимое поля В2.

То, что ниже - на уровне бреда, но проверьте, хуже не будет :) =1=>Тип переменной port - строка, числовые данные в эту переменную записываются строкой. Но мало ли, какой-то глюк преобразования даных... Попробуйте в ячейку записать  порт текстом ("456"). =2=> Еще вариант- сначала данные с листа записать в массив.

Изменил одну строку.
ip = Replace(Replace(Range("A2").Value, Chr(10), ""), " ", "")
Все стало работать правильно.

Спасибо за помошь !!!
